# Cocos2d - Animation + centring camera on a sprite?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite-sheet

I've been following [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1163/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d) tutorial to create a tilebased map and get a character moving around. I then followed [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d) tutorial to add in sprite animation for the movement. I came up with something like the following for movement:

```
[self stopAction: cameraMoveAction];
[playerSprite stopAction:playerMoveAction];
[playerSprite runAction: targetAction];

self.playerMoveAction = [CCSequence actions:
                         [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration: MOVEMENT_SPEED * 4 position: newPosition],
                         [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget: self selector: @selector(finishedMoving)],
                         nil
                         ];

self.cameraMoveAction = [CCSequence actions:
                         [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration: MOVEMENT_SPEED * 4 position: [self calculateNewCenterOfScreen: newPosition]],
                         nil
                         ];

[self runAction: cameraMoveAction];
[playerSprite runAction: playerMoveAction];
```

So if you see, I am moving both the player and the camera (in order to keep the player centered all the time). I had also tried centring the camera on the player in the `finishedMoving` call, but that looked very bad (the player would move, then the camera would jerk to the players location).

Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try CCFollow action which follows the given node automatically. When you move your player, just call something like,

[layer runAction: [CCFollow actionWithTarget:playerNode]];

Comment: Awesome, that worked great! I love that I only need to call it once on the `init` function and it just continues to work. Thanks!